# Is their away to get a result from the startActivity method?

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

Essentially, i am creating a camera class and in the camera class i am calling an intent to use the phones camera. However, I am not able to get and display the picture because I am not using the startActivityForResult method in the class. the startActivityForResult method doesn't work in my class so i used startActivity method instead. I tried creating a class method to pass the pictures' bitmap to the mainActivity sos that I can display the image in an imageview but it wont work. Heres my code if you have in suggestions to my issue:

```
import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class cameraLIBRARY{

    private final Context mContext;
    private Bitmap imageBitmap;
    private Bundle Bundle;

    public static String logtag = "Cam";
    private static int PICTURE = 1;
    private Uri imageUri;

    //class constructor
    public cameraLIBRARY(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void takePhoto(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "pic.jpg");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);

        mContext.startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about startActivityForResult?

Comment: When i use startActivityForResult in my class. the app terminates because it can't open the camera. When i use startActivity, the camera opens just fine.

Comment: Essentially, i implemented the example from this website ( http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html ) in my own class and it wont work. However, when i implement it in MainActivity it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` instead of just startActivity.  You will handle the result in the override method

```
onActivityResult()
```

See [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) for complete details.

One word of caution on handling images from the camera in a non-native app - images can often exceed the 16Mb limit given to non-native apps.  This means that if you don't properly scale your images, your virtual machine will run out of memory!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use startActivity for result just like this

```
startActivityForResult(intent , 2);
```

and then override the onActivityResult Method do you code there like this:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 2)
    {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    {
                // Your code here ...
            }

        }
    }
```

Hope it helps and for futher help please read android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use singletone with listener combination. Not the best solution.

```
public class DataTransfer {
    private static DataTransfer instance;
    private DataTransferListener listener;
    private DataTransfer(){

    }

    public DataTransfer getInstance(){
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new DataTransfer();
        return instance;
    }

    public void setDataTransferListener(DataTransferListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void sendMessage(Object obj){
        if(listener != null)
            listener.onDataReceived(obj);
    }
}

public interface DataTransferListener{
    void onDataReceived(Object obj);
}
```

Then just implement DataTransferListener in your activity and call:

```
DataTransfer.getInstanse().setDataTransferListener(this);
```

Then you can call from where you want

```
DataTransfer.getInstanse().sendMessage(Object);
```

Be aware memory leaks. Call in onDestroy()

```
DataTransfer.getInstanse().setDataTransferListener(null);
```